# Updating on the current id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to update my pivot table using radio button. Where I don't need to go to another url. But it doesn't get the values of radio button when performing update. Here how it looks.

```
//SELECT
Route::get('/documents/pending/view/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@readDocumentsSentForApproval',
    'as' => 'document.viewPending',
]);
//UPDATE
Route::post('/documents/pending/view/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@updateApprovalsDocument',
    'as' => 'document.viewPending',
]);
```

Controller:

```
public function readDocumentsSentForApproval($id)
{
    $viewPendingDocuments = DB::table('approvals_document')
        ->select('documents.title', 'documents.content', 'categories.category_type', 'documents.id')
        ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'approvals_document.document_id')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')
        ->where('documents.id', '=', $id)
        ->first();

    $getApprovers = DB::table('approvals_document')
        ->select('users.first_name', 'users.middle_name', 'users.last_name', 'users.username', 'approvals_document.updated_at', 'approvals_document.isApprove', 'approvals_document.id', 'approvals_document.approver_id')
        ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'approvals_document.document_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'approvals_document.approver_id')
        ->where('documents.id', '=', $id)
        ->get();

    return view ('document.viewPending')
        ->with('viewPendingDocuments', $viewPendingDocuments)
        ->with('getApprovers', $getApprovers);
}

public function updateApprovalsDocument(Request $request)
{
                        //Getting the hidden input named = id.
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $document = DB::table('approvals_document')
        ->where('approvals_document.id', '=', $id)
        ->update(['isApprove' => $request->status, 'updated_at' => new DateTime]);

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

View

```
@foreach($getApprovers as $list)
<tr>

  <td>

  @if(Auth::id() == $list->approver_id)
  <form class="form-inline" id="submitMe" method="post" action="{{ url('documents/pending/view' . $list->id) }}">

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $list->id }}">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" onclick="showApprove()" name="status" value="1">Approve</label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" onclick="showReject()" name="status" value="2">Reject</label>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">

  </form>
  @endif

</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I passed the current url on the action so it will know what `id` is it. Is this the proper way updating? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with it, but I think the recommended way in Laravel would be to use the `patch` route, as this is the RESTful way of doing it.

`post` would be used for creating the entity, `patch` is used for updating it.

The only changes you would need to make, is the route binding (post to patch) and adding the form spoofing for the method
`<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#form-method-spoofing

You could also use the route binding for the id, instead of passing it in as a form field. This would be more advantageous if you wanted to do validation on that route (e.g. a middleware, allowing only the owner of that record to update it).

Comment: I already find a solution with a use of Form Model Binding :D

Answer (score 0):

I already find a solution for this using **Form Method Spoofing**

```
public function readDocumentsSentForApproval($id)
{
    $viewPendingDocuments = DB::table('approvals_document')
        ->select('documents.title', 'documents.content', 'categories.category_type', 'documents.id')
        ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'approvals_document.document_id')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')
        ->where('documents.id', '=', $id)
        ->first();

    $getApprovers = DB::table('approvals_document')
        ->select('users.first_name', 'users.middle_name', 'users.last_name', 'users.username', 'approvals_document.updated_at', 'approvals_document.isApprove', 'approvals_document.approver_id',
        'approvals_document.id as approvalDocumentId', 'documents.id as documentId')
        ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'approvals_document.document_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'approvals_document.approver_id')
        ->where('documents.id', '=', $id)
        ->get();

    return view ('document.viewPending')
        ->with('viewPendingDocuments', $viewPendingDocuments)
        ->with('getApprovers', $getApprovers);
}
```

View:

```
<form class = "form-inline" role = "form" id = "submitMe" method = "POST" action = "/documents/pending/{{ $list->documentId}}/view">

     {{ method_field('PATCH') }}

     <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "{{ $list->approvalDocumentId }}">

     <div class = "form-group">

        <label><input type = "radio" onclick = "showApprove()" name = "status" value = "1"> Approve</label>
        <label><input type = "radio" onclick = "showReject()" name = "status" value = "2"> Reject</label>

     </div>

     <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>
```